# fgetcsv splitting columns in odd places

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to get fgetcsv() to read a comma separated value file. Ordinarily this works as expected, but I've encountered a file that has some columns being split into new data lines instead of being treated as one.

Here is an example of a lines giving me trouble:
[pastie.org/5664800](http://pastie.org/5664800)

The column that is creating the problem is the one with the multiple lines that make up the description.

fgetcsv ends the first read when it reaches the following line:

```
- Length/Width/Height: 3.75\""x2.4\""x2.4\"" (95.25X60.96x60.96)
```

So for instance, if I have the code:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

while ($row = fgetcsv($filepointer, 5000, ',', '"') {
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($row); echo '</pre><br />';
}
```

I get one mostly complete row of data that ends in "`Length/Width/Height: 3.75\"x2.4\""x2.4\"" (95.25X60.96x60.96)`" and then every newline after that is treated as its own row all the way down to the end.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Strange. [It works for me.](http://ideone.com/wlaIGU) What's your PHP version?

Comment: That is odd. It's PHP 5.3.16.

Comment: Hmm. It works on PHP 5.3.10 on my computer, as well as on IDEone's 5.2.12.  Just to make sure, could you download my test script from IDEone and check whether it fails for you?

Comment: Now I see why you didn't get the same results. I screwed up and posted the wrong snippet. This part of the CSV file reproduces the issue in your code, if you would please check: http://pastie.org/5664800

Comment: The link to the file is no more. This question doesn't have a very clear [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your data contains the character sequence `\""`.  From the context, it's clear that this is *supposed* to represent the literal substring `\"`; that is, the blackslash is supposed to be a literal backslash, while the double quote has been escaped by doubling it.

By default, however, [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) treats the backslash as an escape character, so it parses the characters `\"` as a backslash-escaped literal double quote, and then assumes that the second `"` ends the double-quoted string.

The fix is simple, as long as you're using PHP 5.3.0 or later: just tell `fgetcsv()` not to treat the backslash as an escape character by passing some other character as the fifth parameter to it.  Apparently, passing `null` or `false` or `''` won't work to disable the escape character entirely, but passing `'"'` (i.e. the same value as the quote character) does:

```
while ( $row = fgetcsv( $filepointer, 0, ',', '"', '"' ) ) {
    var_export( $row );
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a ton! This actually solved a whole chain reaction of problems. :D

Comment: This is a great bit of info!! Im sure it will save many others. Thanks!!

Comment: Now we just need the same argument for fputcsv so we can actually round-trip RFC compliant CSV...

Answer (score 0):

The fifth argument to [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) is how to escape the " enclosure character when it occurs within the enclosed string

Comment: The problem being that the `"` character doesn't seem to be escaped at all in his data.

Comment: @Sammitch The double quotes are escaped by doubling them like ""